# How to update X% of rows to A, Y% of rows to B, Z% of rows to C

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a table like this:

```
Products
(
   ID int not null primary key,
   Type int not null,
   Route varchar(20) null
)
```

I have a list on the client in this format:

```
Type=1, Percent=0.4, Route=A
Type=1, Percent=0.4, Route=B
Type=1, Percent=0.2, Route=C
Type=2, Percent=0.5, Route=A
Type=2, Percent=0.5, Route=B
Type=3, Percent=1.0, Route=C
...etc
```

When done, I'd like to assign 40% of type 1 products to Route A, 40% to Route B and 20% to Route C. Then 50% of type 2 products to Route A and 50% of type 2 products to Route B, etc.

Is there some way to do this in a single update statement?

If not in one giant statement, can it be done in one statement per type or one statement per route? As currently we're doing one per type+route any of the above would be an improvement.

Comment: "Percent" in your list is rather misleading if the number that follows is not actually the percentage.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Also, can you post code or pseudocode of your current solution?

Comment: SQL Server 2008. And how is 0.4 not a percent? Is 40.0 better? I assume 0.4 is better because 0.4*count(*) is the number of rows to update.

Comment: @WaleedKhan It seems like percents to me (percent per Type)

Comment: @ypercube 0.4 is a *very* low percent, then.

Comment: @WaleedKhan 0.4 means 40%. `0.4 = 4/10 = 40/100`, simple math.

Comment: If you are talking about the correct usage of the term "percent" and some other term is more appropriate, you may be correct. English is not my first language.

Comment: @ypercube is correct. 40% is shorthand for 40 over 100 or 40/100 which equals .4

Comment: The current solution would be for each ID/Type, run this update in a loop until every product has a route: Update products set route='A' where type=1 and id in (select top 40 percent from products where type=1 and route is null)

Comment: @ypercube 0.4 = 40%. I find it misleading to put Percent=0.4, which implies that it is 0.4%, not 0.4 or 40%.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an Oracle statement that I prepared before you posted that you were using SQL-Server, but it might give you some ideas, though you will have to roll your own ratio_to_report analytic function using CTE and self-joins. We calculate the cumulative proportion of each type in the products and client route tables and do a non equi-join on the matching proportion bands. The sample data I have used has some round-offs but these will reduce for larger data sets.

Here's the setup:

```
create table products (id int not null primary key, "type" int not null, route varchar (20) null);
create table clienttable ( "type" int not null, percent number (10, 2) not null, route varchar (20) not null);
insert into clienttable ("type", percent, route) values (1, 0.4, 'A');
insert into clienttable ("type", percent, route) values (1, 0.4, 'B');
insert into clienttable ("type", percent, route) values (1, 0.2, 'C');
insert into clienttable ("type", percent, route) values (2, 0.5, 'A');
insert into clienttable ("type", percent, route) values (2, 0.5, 'B');
insert into clienttable ("type", percent, route) values (3, 1.0, 'C');

insert into products (id, "type", route) values (1, 1, null);
insert into products (id, "type", route) values (2, 1, null);
insert into products (id, "type", route) values (3, 1, null);
insert into products (id, "type", route) values (4, 1, null);
insert into products (id, "type", route) values (5, 1, null);
insert into products (id, "type", route) values (6, 1, null);
insert into products (id, "type", route) values (7, 1, null);
-- 7 rows for product type 1 so we will expect 3 of route A, 3 of route B, 1 of route C (rounded)

insert into products (id, "type", route) values (8, 2, null);
insert into products (id, "type", route) values (9, 2, null);
insert into products (id, "type", route) values (10, 2, null);
insert into products (id, "type", route) values (11, 2, null);
insert into products (id, "type", route) values (12, 2, null);
-- 5 rows for product type 2 so we will expect 3 of route A and 2 of route B (rounded)

insert into products (id, "type", route) values (13, 3, null);
insert into products (id, "type", route) values (14, 3, null);
-- 2 rows for product type 3 so we will expect 2 of route C
```

and here's the statement

```
select prods.id, prods."type", client.route cr from
(
select
p.id, 
p."type", 
row_number () over (partition by p."type" order by p.id) / count (*) over (partition by p."type") cum_ratio
from
products p
) prods
inner join 
(
select "type", route, nvl (lag (cum_ratio, 1) over (partition by "type" order by route), 0) ratio_start, cum_ratio ratio_end from 
(select "type", route, sum (rr) over (partition by "type" order by route) cum_ratio
from (select c."type", c.route, ratio_to_report (c.percent) over (partition by "type") rr from clienttable c))) client 
on prods."type" = client."type" 
and prods.cum_ratio >= client.ratio_start and prods.cum_ratio < client.ratio_end
```

This gives the following result:-

```
+----+------+----+
| ID | type | CR |
+----+------+----+
|  1 |    1 | A  |
|  2 |    1 | A  |
|  3 |    1 | B  |
|  4 |    1 | B  |
|  5 |    1 | B  |
|  6 |    1 | C  |
|  8 |    2 | A  |
|  9 |    2 | A  |
| 10 |    2 | B  |
| 11 |    2 | B  |
| 13 |    3 | C  |
+----+------+----+
```

Answer (score 0):

How about something like

```
--For updating type 1, set every route for type 1 as null.

UPDATE MyTable
SET [Route] = null
WHERE [Type] = '1'

--Update Route A(40%)
DECLARE @myVal int;
SET @myVal  =CAST(0.4*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE [Type]='1') AS INT);
WITH    tab AS
    (
    SELECT  TOP (@myVal) *
    FROM myTable
    )
UPDATE  tab
SET     [Route] = 'A'
WHERE [Route] is null

--Update Route B (40%)
DECLARE @myVal int;
SET @myVal  =CAST(0.4*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE [Type]='1') AS INT);
WITH    tab AS
    (
    SELECT  TOP (@myVal) *
    FROM myTable
    )
UPDATE  tab
SET     [Route] = 'B'
WHERE [Route] is null


--Update Route C (20%)
DECLARE @myVal int;
SET @myVal  =CAST(0.2*(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM myTable WHERE [Type]='1') AS INT);
WITH    tab AS
    (
    SELECT  TOP (@myVal) *
    FROM myTable
    )
UPDATE  tab
SET     [Route] = 'C'
WHERE [Route] is null
```

Comment: Maybe I'm not seeing it, but isn't this still one update per type per route which I'm already doing? Also, you can "select top X percent" from a table so you can skip the counting steps. I'm thinking the solution, if there is one, would be a big case statement.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if similar functionality exist in SQL Server. In Oracle there is SAMPLE clause.
Below query selects 10% of rows from a table:

```
SELECT empno
  FROM scott.emp
SAMPLE (10)
/
```

Then your update would be easy... Maybe smth similar exists in SQL Server. You can also count rows or data then calc percent then update...

Comment: In the comments, I said we're doing this in a loop: Update products set route='A' where type=1 and id in (select top 40 percent from products where type=1 and route is null) So the update is not hard, but I'd like to reduce the number of updates.

Answer (score 0):

```
WITH po AS
  ( SELECT 
        ID,
        Type,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY Type
                            ORDER BY ID
                          ) AS Rn,
        COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY Type) AS CntType
    FROM
          Products
  )    
, ro AS
  ( SELECT 
        Type,
        Route,
        ( SELECT SUM(rr.Percent) 
          FROM Route AS rr 
          WHERE rr.Type = r.Type 
            AND rr.Route <= r.Route
        ) AS SumPercent 
    FROM
          Routes AS r
  )
UPDATE p
SET p.Route =
            ( SELECT MIN(ro.Route) 
              FROM ro 
              WHERE ro.Type = po.Type 
                AND ro.SumPercent >= po.Rn / po.CntType
            )
FROM    Products AS p
    JOIN
        po   ON po.ID = p.ID ;
```